# Как узнать об аварийном закрытии программы на c#?

Tags: c#, исключения

Тестирую программу, не могу везде написать `try... except`. Можно ли как-то при аварийном закрытии программы вывести сообщение пользователю типа "Аварийное закрытие программы, запомните, пожалуйста, Ваши последние действия"?

Answer (score 5):

Если вы хотите перехватывать все необработанные исключения в вашем приложении, подпишитесь на AppDomain.UnhandledException

```
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags=SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlAppDomain)]
public static void TestSomeException()
{
    AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    domain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(SomeExceptionHandler);

    throw new Exception("Тестовое исключение");
}

static void SomeExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args) {
    Exception e = (Exception) args.ExceptionObject;
    // TODO: Обработать исключение
}

public static void Main() {
    TestSomeException();
}
```

Comment: А можно поконкретней для неопытных?
Где писать `[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,         Flags=SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlAppDomain)]`?
И я, наверное, не буду обрабатывать ошибку, а просто закрою приложение после messagebox, но this.close не работает в статич. классе. Где мне это написать?

Comment: Атрибут [т.е. то, что в квадратных скобках] нужно приписывать тому методу, который будет устанавливать подписку на событие.

Насчет this.Close() - предлагаю вместо него использовать, например, Application.Exit().